# Content of url is UTF-8, but when I system.out the string it is not UTF-8 anymore

Tags: java, string, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

Content of url is UTF-8, but when I system.out the string it is not UTF-8 anymore. How can I convert the string so it supports utf-8? I am getting some words like this:

```
ObjectgeÃ¶rienteerd
```

I have tried things like byte arrays, inputstreams, etc, but it didn't work.

My code:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
String thatUrl = url[0];
URL urly = new URL(thatUrl);
InputStream is = urly.openStream();
final StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
int counter;
while ((counter = is.read()) != -1) {
    buffer.append((char) counter);
}
```

Comment: You may want to use buffer.toString(). You can also try PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
   out.println(buffer); as it allows setting of encoding.

Comment: @JohnMorrison Those have nothing to do with the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're reading the contents 1 byte at a time with `is.read()`. Some characters in UTF-8 are more than 1 byte. Every time you encounter one of those characters, you break them by converting each separate byte into a char.

A simple solution is to read the contents into a `byte[]` (for example using a `ByteArrayOutputStream`) and when you've got all the bytes, convert them to a `String` with `new String(byteArray, "UTF-8");`.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
int counter;
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; // Let's read up to 1KB at a time, it's faster
while((counter = is.read(buffer)) != -1)
    out.write(buffer, 0, counter);

// String output = new String(out.toByteArray(), "UTF-8");
String output = out.toString("UTF-8"); // Save an extra byte[] allocation
```

Comment: My code, or yours? Because if my code doesn't work, it's a lot more serious than just `:(`.

Comment: it does not work for me unfortunately :( . It still prints it out as weird characters

Comment: Did you copy my code exactly? If you're getting output as "Ã¶", it's just the bytes from "ö" in UTF-8 converted to a String in ISO-8859-1 (or similar) encoding. It's exactly the issue which my code is addressing.

Comment: @Jason So what was the issue (I assume you solved it)?

Comment: I think it had to do with the url or something like that.